# Error 80070005 - I Can't find Microsoft Excel Application or CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} on DCOM

Tags: asp.net, excel, com, clsid

After getting enlightenment from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497169/asp-net-c-sharp-get-file-location-after-downloded) , i've changed the flow.

I asked the user to upload the excel so i can manipulate it later.
and then i got error :

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.**

You can see the screenshot here : https://twitter.com/itsCYD/status/570134973128302592/photo/1

i googled for solution and found this :
https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/error-office-interop-assemblies/

the new problem is, Microsoft Excel Application or CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is not found in DCOM.

and then i install the Interop Assemblies and refresh the DCOM. it's still not there.

Need Help.

Thousand Thanks.

Comment: [Considerations for Server-side automation of office applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) outlines a) a problem "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services)" and b) some possible alternatives. At the moment, your error is that the account your application is running under doesn't have permission to launch excel, but hopefully you can see "fixing" this error would be the wrong thing to do.

Comment: [Problem Solved] I followed instructions on this blog : http://jwcooney.com/2012/09/20/configuring-a-web-server-to-allow-excel-file-creation-via-the-interop-excel-namespace/

Comment: And that was *exactly* the wrong way to solve the problem. I pointed you at an article that describes the problems associated with automating office applications, and you instead found a fix that allowed you to get around your *current* obstacle. With **no** guarantee of stability in the long run.

Comment: I'm clueless. This is the Best (temporary) Solution (for now) for my current problem :)