# Local Physical Address still Appear in Web Server Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm currently developing [a simple ASP .Net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691128/error-80070005-i-cant-find-microsoft-excel-application-or-clsid-00024500-000) application where user will upload excel file to the server.

I got this error :
https://twitter.com/itsCYD/status/571155905611321344/photo/1

My Concern is the path (in the red square) was my local path when i developed it on my notebook. why its still appear?

and then i decide to make the same path on the server and even put the source code (just 1 aspx.cs file), and this is what i got :

(https://twitter.com/itsCYD/status/571155949374693377/photo/1)

what is really going on ?

Comment: Please edit your question and re-post images to default SO storage, or better yet instead of images post text of the error.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I can't do it. The Site told me that i need several reputation in order to be able to post images. that is why i keep using image url instead of posting images.